# Android using One Spinner with Two Adapters

Tags: java, android, spinner, adapter, android-spinner

I have `one spinner, two adapters and two buttons`

when first button is clicked the maleAdapter is called
when the other button is clicked the femaleAdapter is called.
So far this works perfect.

Now. my problem is when each adapter is called two different arrays are called, obviously, BUT i want them to do different things.

```
Spinner spinner;
String[] maleItems = { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3" };
String[] femaleItems = { "item 3", "item 2", "item 1", "item 0" };

Button maleButton;
Button femaleButton;

ArrayAdapter<String> maleAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<String> femaleAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     final ArrayAdapter<String> maleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, maleItems);
     final ArrayAdapter<String> femaleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, femaleItems);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setAdapter(maleAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Buttons
    maleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.maleButton);
    femaleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.femaleButton);

    maleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            spinner.setAdapter(maleAdapter);

        }
    });

    femaleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            spinner.setAdapter(femaleAdapter);

        }
    });

}
```

Here on my onItemSelected i want to change what happens depending on which button is pressed.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
SpinnerAdapter adap = spinner.getAdapter();

if (adap.equals(maleAdapter)) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        // do something only the maleAdapter does
        break;
    case 1:
        // do something only the maleAdapter does
        break;
    case 2:
        // do something only the maleAdapter does
        break;
    }
} else if (adap.equals(femaleAdapter)) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        // do something only the femaleAdapter does
        break;
    case 1:
        // do something only the femaleAdapter does
        break;
    case 2:
        // do something only the femaleAdapter does
        break;
    }
}
}
```

My onClick method worked perfect but the adapter changing gives me an error and i dont know why.

Error

```
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at com.MainActivity.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:117)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
01-25 04:11:18.873: E/AndroidRuntime(21871):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> maleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, maleItems);
```

it is in the local scope of onCreate remove it and initilaize the global maleAdpter over there

just remove final ArrayAdapter before maleAdapter and femaleAdapter.

Comment: wow, i cant believe it was something so simple, i did this and it worked....i left them inside the oncreate and took off the final ArrayAdapter<String> from the beginning and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend keeping two separate `OnItemSelectedListeners`, one for each adapter. Now, when you swap the adapters, also swap the `OnItemSelectedListener`. Plain and simple.

Comment: how would i set the adapter to each OnItemSelectedListener when the adapter is changed?